# I am getting Network Error with localhost in API in react native but i am able to hit with postman I am tring this in Action With Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, networking

```
export const SignuppPostDataOnApi =
  (phone, password, confirm_password) => async dispatch => {
    // console.log('API DATA =>=>,,', phone, password, confpassword);

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    try {
      const body = {
        phone: phone,
        password: password,
        confirm_password: confirm_password,
        user_role: '1',
        accept_terms_and_conditions: '1',
      };

      console.log('data', body);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://192.168.19.10:80/v1/users/signup',
        body,
        config,
      );

      console.log('res===>>', res);

      // if (res.data) {
      //   dispatch({
      //     type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS',
      //     payload: res,
      //   });
      // }

      // return res;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERR', err);
      // return errors;
    }
  }
```

// I am using axios for POST data on API in react-native and i am getting "Network Error" in catch and i am getting undefined in res again and again but When i tried with Postman i am able to post the resquest Please help. i'm using localhost http://localhost:80/v1/users/signup  and i also tried with IP Address but not working. it always saying Network Error. and res undefined.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the error? My first instinct tells me it might be 
a CORS issue.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to POST data on the local API with the help of REDUX I am going this in Action but I am always getting Network Error and I am getting Undefined in response as you can see is my code upper there.  but i am able to POST data with Postman software with same localhost

Comment: Are you running your code in a browser? If yes, can you take a screenshot of the error in the browser console?

Comment: I am using react native cli